# How to read data from socket, until client stopped send?

Tags: sockets, tcp, go

I have some problem.
I have client and server. Client connect with server over TCP. 
Then, client send some data (separated by chunks), I don't know what is the length of data (TLS handshake). But I know that client send some data with fixed length, and then stop, until not received some response, then he send data with fixed length again.

I need read all chunks, until client stopped send (because so many chunks). How to do that ?

I have only one idea, it's timeout. Read data in loop and set timeout between iterate. If timeout is ended, then data complete collected.

Perhaps there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? The question doesn't really make sense as it is.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but generally speaking you the body is represented with an `io.Reader` and you can just read off it until it's end... In the case of a chunked response you are completely abstracted from the individual chunks, you see it as a stream of text data... The same as a body that was served all at once. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JimB Browser (aka client), connect to my server, and proxy https site. For proxy over https, browser send CONNECT request, listen 200 OK response, and then send encrypted data to me, separated by chunks, for example
chunk1 - 167 bytes,
chunk2 - 312 bytes,
chunk3 - 72 bytes
Then browser stops, and waiting response, after receive response browser again send chunks.

I need to collect chunk1, chunk2, chunk3 in one chunk, but i don't know when browser stopped to send chunks, and switch to wait state.

I hope it is now clear :)?

Comment: @sintanial: If you're proxying opaque data, you have no way of knowing when the client is done with a "message". You don't need to collate anything, just send the data to the server.

Comment: @JimB ->You don't need to collate anything, just send the data to the server. -- I know it, but i need to collect chunks (business logic)

Comment: If you can't interpret the underlying data and it's protocol (you said it's encrypted), you have no way to know how many chunks to expect. What you're essentially asking is "how do I read N bytes from a stream, without knowing N?".

Comment: An HTTPS proxy can only copy bytes. The data is encrypted. You can't see inside. The chunks are meaningless to you and they are also meaningless to both peers. Your requirement to 'collect chunks' is also meaningless, and there is no 'business logic' you can implement on encrypted data. Just copy the bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information in your comments, you're doing this wrong. The correct way to write an HTTPS proxy is to read the CONNECT line, make the upstream connection, send the appropriate response back o the client, and then if successful start copying bytes in both directions simultaneously. You're not in the least concerned with packets or read sizes, and you should certainly not make any attempt to 'collect' packets before retransmission, as that will just add latency to the system.

You can accomplish this either by starting two threads per connection, one in each direction, or via non-blocking sockets and `select()/poll()/epoll()`, or whatever that looks like in Go.

**BUT** I have no idea why you're doing this at all. There are plenty of open-source HTTP proxies already in existence, and as you're dealing with HTTPS there is no value you can possibly add to them. Your claim about 'business logic' is meaningless, or at least unimplementable.